# Error trying to publish my web app from VS Enterprise 2015 update 1 to azure:

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, web-deployment

Yesterday when I published this webapp, it said that a new webapp has been created although there is nothing to display. So, as required I installed the Azure SDK updates, etc., - as was recommended by the software ie VS 15 enterprise edition. Today, when I right click on the web app and select Publish I see the following error on my Azure App Service Activity tab:

```
        ------ Build started: Project: BPIT - Publish, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
        ------ Publish started: Project: BPIT - Publish, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
        Can't find existing loaded project:http://localhost:6002

        ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
        ========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Check this for more information.

http://bpitanshika.azurewebsites.net/
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about your code, we cant really tell you why publishing failed. Can you post your code and/or more detailed error logs?

Comment: @AnshikaAgarwal Same problem here.  After making a backup, open your solution file in notepad and see if you have two lines like "Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_<some port number>\" and "Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_<some port number>\".  In my case those directories don't exist.  I'm currently trying to figure out how to fix this.  My guess is those "PrecompiledWeb" directories are being created in the wrong place.

Comment: @AnshikaAgarwal - I'm not putting this solution (workaround) as a an answer because it is not a fix.  But I found that you can publish your web site from WebMatrix 3, a free app from Microsoft.  Just open the solution folder as a web site.  When you get the publish dialogue, choose your existing or add a new web site on Azure.  It's ugly but it works, especially if you're in a crunch to get your web site work done.

Comment: The problem has been solved... After it shows that publish 1 failed, Goto Azure App Service Activity tab and click the publish icon. Your website will publish.-@RobertOschler

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error publishing ASP.Net Websites (not Web app) to Azure. 
Here's how to fix it:

1. On Visual Studio click View -  Other Windows - Web Publish Activity
2. This will bring up Azure App Service Activity window
3. Click on Publish icon

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/acoat/2016/01/28/publish-a-static-web-site-using-azure-web-apps/

Comment: Oh heck... Seriously ?  First off, thank you... this fixed my problem... but why has Microsoft broken the regular "Publish web app" option, and left it broken ?  I thought they *wanted* us to easily use Azure...  Btw, I tried to re-download the Publish Profile from Azure, tried publishing using that, and same error.  So it looks like this hidden-away "Publish" button is the only way to Publish from VS2015...